# How to get the name attribute from an HTML object

Tags: javascript, html

I have several SPAN tags with content that a user can click on, and the only attribute that I can rely on is the 'name' attribute.
Unfortunately in my javascript I get 'undefined' even though the ID attribute shows me I'm on the correct object. (but I can't use ID as there are several objects with the same name, but different id's)

Here's my HTML tag:

```
 <SPAN id='br1' name='slider'>Some Content</span>
 <SPAN id='br2' name='slider'>Some other Content</span>
```

In my javascript:

```
document.onmousedown=myMouseDown;
function myMouseDown(e){
    if (!e) var e = window.event;
    var selected_item= e.srcElement
    alert(selected_item.tagName+' '+selected_item.id+' '+selected_item.name);
 }
```

The result is : SPAN br1 undefined
(in IE10 and in Chrome, HTML5)

Comment: Try use `class=""` (in Javascript `selected_item.className`)

Comment: @GuilhermeNascimento Why are you talking about classes?

Comment: Because `name` is not a valid attribute on span elements, I guess. Use `data-name` instead...

Comment: @lan the problem is the use of it, he's trying to use "name", when in his case "className" would fit best.

Comment: @GuilhermeNascimento You still haven't given a reason why that's "better". AndreaParodi's comment is the only real reason - `name` isn't a valid attribute for `<span>`s. While using `class` is definitely an option, the real solution is to use a `data-*` attribute, unless the OP expects to apply CSS to all the elements. It really depends on what the OP wants to use it for - just selecting the elements, or associating information with them.

Comment: @lan The "class attribute" is used with various purposes. Obviously the `date-*` attribute can also be a better use compared to the "name attribute". But if you observe several codes that use similar elements (eg. sliders gallery) often use the "class" attribute. I really think this is completely irrelevant to compare `date-*` with `class=""`.

Comment: @GuilhermeNascimento I'm not trying to argue between using `class` and `data-*`...it's just that you never, and still haven't, given a real reason why to use either in comparison to `name` ("it fits best" isn't a good explanation). As I've already pointed out, it depends on what the OP is trying to accomplish with a **name** (or **class**). If they're trying to associate data with it, they should use something more like `name` (like `data-name`), but if they're simply trying to group elements, then `class` is perfectly fine, no doubt. It's hard to get data from a `class` attribute

Comment: @GuilhermeNascimento Point of interest: you can apply CSS based on attributes with attribute selectors, and those work in *IE7*. I agree that data-\* is for data and .class is for CSS, but if you're using data-\* for data, you can have CSS based on the data. Also, I think its reasonable to presume that the OP knows about .class and would have used that if they were working with CSS. I'm guessing that's what Andrea did.

Comment: @lan I'm not being against the use of `data-*`, I just commented that his case for the `.className` can be a good use. In this case use `class=""` or `data-*` is a matter of choice. In other words, does not matter which is used. Agree get class can actually be more difficult if you use multiple classes on an element. In this case a little "RegExp" already solved. I hope you understand now. :)

Comment: @acbabis I agree, but will complement, he said that everyone is using the same name, so using "data-*" or "class" is just a matter of choice. But if he actually store data or names with variant characters, complex text data is certainly the best choice.

Answer (score 1):

Use `selected_item.getAttribute('name')`

```
document.onmousedown=myMouseDown;
function myMouseDown(e){
    if (!e) var e = window.event;
    var selected_item= e.srcElement
    alert(selected_item.tagName+' '+selected_item.id+' '+selected_item.getAttribute('name'));
}
```